# Problems caused by using Transition

Tags: android, android-animation, transition

[Problem of figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oigoM.gif)

[Problem of figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF0pC.gif)

Sorry for my bad english. I am facing this problem since a long time, but I still can't solve it. There is no problem when I use the system's own ChangeBounds. But when I put Main2Acivity in transition and SetDuration(3000); After deleting the animation there is no task problem.

My code is as follows：

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,findViewById(R.id.iv),"iv");
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class),  activityOptionsCompat.toBundle());

        }
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        MyTransition transition = new MyTransition();
        transition.addTarget("iv");
        transition.setDuration(3000);
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);

    }
}
```

---

```java
public class MyTransition extends Transition {
    @Override
    public void captureStartValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
        Log.e("FMY", "captureStartValues:" + transitionValues.view.hashCode());

        transitionValues.values.put("x", transitionValues.view.getX());
        transitionValues.values.put("y", transitionValues.view.getY());

    }

    @Override
    public void captureEndValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
        Log.e("FMY", "captureEndValues:" + transitionValues.view.hashCode());

        transitionValues.values.put("x", transitionValues.view.getX());
        transitionValues.values.put("y", transitionValues.view.getY());

    }


    @Override
    public Animator createAnimator(ViewGroup sceneRoot, TransitionValues startValues, TransitionValues endValues) {

        Log.e("FMY", "createAnimator");
//        endValues.view.setTranslationX();
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyValuesHolderX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", ((Float) startValues.values.get("x")), ((Float) endValues.values.get("x")));
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyValuesHolderY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", ((Float) startValues.values.get("y")), ((Float) endValues.values.get("y")));
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(endValues.view, propertyValuesHolderX,propertyValuesHolderY);

        objectAnimator.setDuration(3000);
        return objectAnimator;

    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/rott"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">

<ImageView
        android:transitionName="iv"
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="230dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation is executed with its view mobile dockerView as the parent layout